# ORACLE feed regexp match to function

Tags: regex, oracle, date-arithmetic

how do you apply a function to a regexp match?

My goal is: convert ALL unis timestamp in a text field to human-readable datetime

Unixtimestamp can be extracted by

```
regexp (\d{10}' || chr(4) ||')
```

So now i have

```
SELECT 
   HISTODETAILS,
   regexp_replace(HISTODETAILS,'(\d{10}' || chr(4) ||')','\1')  HISTODETAILS2
FROM <table>
WHERE .....
```

and i'd like to apply a function to the `\1`

```
SELECT 
   HISTODETAILS,
   regexp_replace(HISTODETAILS,'(\d{10}' || chr(4) ||')',myfunction('\1'))  HISTODETAILS2
FROM <table>
WHERE .....
```

First of all, do you think this can be done?
Should this be the case.... how? :)

TIA

EDIT:
I should have mentiond that there might be multiple occurrence of the timestamp 
i.e.

```
1398929938
this and that , bla bla bla

1400587008
more bla bla bla

1400587395
once more bla bla bla
```

and the final result should be

```
2014-05-01 09:38:58
this and that , bla bla bla

2014-05-20 13:56:48
more bla bla bla

2014-05-20 14:03:15
once more bla bla bla
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183912/is-it-possible-to-regexp-replace-using-a-function) is something similar

Answer (score 0):

A unix timestamp is simply the number of seconds (sometimes milliseconds but yours are ten digits, so seconds) since the unix epoch.  So, having extracted the unix timestamp with a regex, we can convert them to regular dates quite easily by using simple date arithmetic like this:

```
select date '1970-01-01' 
       + to_number(
                regexp_replace(HISTODETAILS, '(\d{10})' || chr(4), '\1')
                  ) /86400) 
from your_table
/
```

To get the format you want you'll need to apply the appropriate mask e.g.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-dd-mm hh24:mi:ss'
/
```

Comment: Hi APC, thanks for answering. I receive an ORA-01722 when i enclose the regexp_replace in the to_number function.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to use a function to create the value, I would put the regexp_replace also inside that function.

```
select histodetails, myfunction(histodetails) 
from   table
where  ...
```

and the function

```
create or replace myfunction(p_histodetails)
return varchar2
as
  v_value varchar2(30); -- or whatever
begin
  -- create stuff to replace with
  v_value := '' -- TODO
  -- return the regexp
  return regexp_replace(p_histodetails,'(\d{10}' || chr(4) ||')', v_value)
end
```

Comment: Not going to work. If i feed the whole text field to the function, i'll be in the same position i am right now. The text field is a diary field and has multiple occurences of timestamp i have to turn to datetime